# How the grab only the visible HTML without the CSS?

Tags: javascript

```
getHTMLOfSelection: function() {
    var range;
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        // this.document.execCommand("Copy", true);
        return range.htmlText;
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(clonedSelection);

            var elms = div.querySelectorAll("*[style]");
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(elms, function(elm) {
                var clr = elm.style.display || "";
                if (clr === 'none') {
                    elm.innerText = '';
                }
            });

            return div.innerHTML;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

This is my code but it is not working in the case when the CSS is written with respect to `class,id` such as `display:none`, `visiblity:hidden` and `height:0`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is not working 'in respect to' those things? What is the actual behavior and what did you expect?

Comment: thank you for the reply,
using the above function i am able to grab the innerHTML but the issue is that the function in grabbing all the HTML including the hidden one, means those which are made hidden by using css like (display:none,visibility:hidden and height:0). i do not want these hidden HTML

Comment: `elm.style` will give you the style of that specific element as set using JavaScript or by the `style` attribute. 

Use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the computed style of that element. That should allow you to skip over the hidden elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with `:visible`